# Reading text in Linux shell and writing some specific rows to a new file

Tags: linux, shell, read-text

I have a file with information with this format (input.txt):

```
045002   1987244NDBC North L. Mich. 453086401 176  5
045002   1999140NDBC North L. Mich. 453186421 176  5
045002   2006117NDBC North L. Mich. 453386421 176  5
045002   2007127NDBC North L. Mich. 453386431 176  5
045002   2009138NDBC North L. Mich. 453486411 176  5
045007   1987244NDBC South L. Mich. 427087101 176  5
045007   1991091NDBC South L. Mich. 428087101 176  5
045007   1991154NDBC South L. Mich. 427087101 176  5
045007   1995237NDBC South L. Mich. 427087001 176  5
045007   1999140NDBC South L. Mich. 426787021 176  5
045007   2006117NDBC South L. Mich. 426887031 176  5
045007   2009127NDBC South L. Mich. 426787031 176  5
045007   2010133NDBC South L. Mich. 427086971 176  5
045007   2011145NDBC South L. Mich. 426887031 176  5
045007   2012100NDBC South L. Mich. 426787031 176  5
045013   2012212UWM Atwater Park WI 431087851 176  2
045014   2012224UWM Green Bay WI    448087761 176  2
045018   2011222CPD MontroseBeach IL419787641 176  3 00011110
045020   2007230UGLOS GrandTrav Bay 447985601 176  2
```

I need to read this file in a Linux shell and create an output file that contains some specific rows of the input file based on the number in the first column, e.g., 045002, 045013, 045018. The output file (output.txt) should look like this:

```
045002   1987244NDBC North L. Mich. 453086401 176  5
045002   1999140NDBC North L. Mich. 453186421 176  5
045002   2006117NDBC North L. Mich. 453386421 176  5
045002   2007127NDBC North L. Mich. 453386431 176  5
045002   2009138NDBC North L. Mich. 453486411 176  5
045013   2012212UWM Atwater Park WI 431087851 176  2
045018   2011222CPD MontroseBeach IL419787641 176  3 00011110
```

Comment: What is the rule for the numbers in the first column? The examples you gave do not show a clear pattern. Do you just want a specific number?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If *numbers.txt* is a list of numbers:

```
sed 's/.*/^&/' numbers.txt | grep -f - input.txt > output.txt
```

Or the numbers can be on the command line:

```
printf "^%s\n" 045002 045013 045018 | grep -f - input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: This would give false positives if any of the numbers in `numbers.txt` matches any _other_ column in the `input.txt` file. For example, if one number was `087101`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, Thanks.  See revised answer.

Comment: Better, but you would have to match the `[[:blank:]]` _after_ the number as well, or `^1234` would match `12345`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, That seems overgeneral.  Given the leading zeros, it's reasonable to assume a six-digit first column for both *numbers.txt* and *input.txt*.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have a file, `numbers`, containing

```
045002
045013
045018
```

Then you could do

```
awk 'NR == FNR { n[$1] = 1; next } $1 in n' numbers input.txt >output.txt
```

The `awk` program takes the `numbers` file and your `input.txt` file as input.  The first block is only executed for the `numbers` file and simply creates an associative array with the numbers as keys.  When we reach the second file, we test the number in the first column to see whether it's a key in the array. If it is, the whole line is printed.

This would produce `output.txt` as

```
045002   1987244NDBC North L. Mich. 453086401 176  5
045002   1999140NDBC North L. Mich. 453186421 176  5
045002   2006117NDBC North L. Mich. 453386421 176  5
045002   2007127NDBC North L. Mich. 453386431 176  5
045002   2009138NDBC North L. Mich. 453486411 176  5
045013   2012212UWM Atwater Park WI 431087851 176  2
045018   2011222CPD MontroseBeach IL419787641 176  3 00011110
```

If you'd like the `awk` program to be fully explicit:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { n[$1] = 1; next } NR != FNR && ($1 in n) { print }' numbers input.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: This answer correctly checks for a desired number in the _first column_, and not just _anywhere_ on the line.